# Will I get SSN automatically or I have to apply for it?

Tags: usa, visa, paperwork, social-security

I have just arrived in USA 2 days ago.

I have family-visa F4 category.

I need to know that will I have to apply for SSN

or I will receive my SSN automatically because I requested for SSN when I filled my `DS-260 form`.

Answer (score 2):

If you asked for an SSN on the DS-260 the SSA will automatically mail the card to the address where you'll receive your green card once they are notified that you have entered the US.  [This reference](https://www.socialsecurity.gov/ssnvisa/Handout_11_1.html) says you should complain if you don't get the card within 3 weeks.

Comment: ?? F-4 is an immigrant visa (i.e. green card).  DS-260 is the form you fill out to apply for consular processing of an immigrant visa.  Once (s)he's got the visa from a consulate and entered the US on it (s)he's good to work.

Comment: Sorry! My mistake, I was mixing it up with a dependent of student visa. I'm deleting my original comment.